Fixed Header Moves Down with Gap When Scrolling in WordPress
I'm having trouble with the header of my WordPress website. When I scroll down the page, the header follows the scroll but leaves a gap at the top, rather than sticking firmly to the top of the viewport. Here’s a screenshot for reference:

I have applied CSS to make the header fixed.

Despite the CSS, the header shifts down when I scroll, creating a gap.

There is no margin or padding customization option in the theme settings to adjust this.

How can I ensure the header sticks to the top without leaving a gap when scrolling?



try scrolling without being logged in with admin bar. When you are with admin you have extra class that  you can use to fix your header position.
